# ElasticSearch DSL query not working on a specific field

Tags: elasticsearch, dsl

I am querying a ElasticSearch database. My documents are structured as follows:

```
    {
      "uuid": "5035732b-9ba8-4cf7-96a7-6d1c7e179fec",
      "name": "LTK_1604d0",
      "recording_datetime": "2021-10-10T08:08:13",
      "stopped_recording_datetime": "2021-10-11T06:53:12",
      "created": "2021-10-11T17:25:16.754278",
      "source": "U",
      "file": "ISO-XML_LTK_15f407_LTK_15f9a0_LTK_15fc07_LTK_15fed7_LTK_15ffcb (1).zip",
      "data_format": "p",
      "data_type": "ISOBUS",
      "data_set_rois": [],
      "dataset_measurements": [
        {
            "id": 1995250,
            "index": 2,
            "name": "iso_013A",
            "unit": "%",
            "device": "49700062",
            "code": "iso_013A",
            "count": 8067,
            "std": 21.233523112224,
            "min": 0.0,
            "max": 55.0,
            "mean": 18.4815544812198,
            "percentiles": [
                0.0,
                0.0,
                0.0,
                0.0,
                0.0,
                0.0,
                0.0,
                0.0,
                0.0,
                0.0,
                0.0,
                40.0,
                40.5,
                40.7,
                41.0,
                41.5,
                42.2,
                43.3,
                45.8
            ],
            "prio": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 1995248,
            "index": 0,
            "name": "iso_0054",
            "unit": "t/ha",
            "device": "49700062",
            "code": "iso_0054",
            "count": 8067,
            "std": 37.4462960389206,
            "min": 0.0,
            "max": 412.41,
            "mean": 26.6444713028387,
            "percentiles": [
                0.0,
                0.0,
                0.0,
                0.0,
                0.0,
                0.0,
                0.0,
                0.0,
                0.0,
                0.0,
                0.0,
                21.62,
                47.329,
                54.652,
                58.21,
                61.188,
                64.041,
                68.034,
                79.57
            ],
            "prio": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 1995253,
            "index": 5,
            "name": "iso_E107+107",
            "unit": "U/min",
            "device": "49700062",
            "code": "iso_E107+107",
            "count": 8067,
            "std": 617.86811828088,
            "min": 0.0,
            "max": 2129.0,
            "mean": 1406.03780835503,
            "percentiles": [
                0.0,
                0.0,
                998.0,
                999.0,
                999.0,
                1002.0,
                1284.1,
                1500.4,
                1598.0,
                1659.0,
                1701.0,
                1729.0,
                1762.0,
                1810.0,
                1856.0,
                1931.0,
                1991.0,
                2030.0,
                2049.0
            ],
            "prio": 2
        },
        {
            "id": 1995252,
            "index": 4,
            "name": "iso_E104+107",
            "unit": " ",
            "device": "49700062",
            "code": "iso_E104+107",
            "count": 8067,
            "std": 0.0,
            "min": 52.0,
            "max": 52.0,
            "mean": 52.0,
            "percentiles": [
                52.0,
                52.0,
                52.0,
                52.0,
                52.0,
                52.0,
                52.0,
                52.0,
                52.0,
                52.0,
                52.0,
                52.0,
                52.0,
                52.0,
                52.0,
                52.0,
                52.0,
                52.0,
                52.0
            ],
            "prio": 2
        },
        {
            "id": 1995251,
            "index": 3,
            "name": "iso_018D",
            "unit": "km/h",
            "device": "49700062",
            "code": "iso_018D",
            "count": 8067,
            "std": 9.64427850775535,
            "min": 0.0,
            "max": 45.07,
            "mean": 6.29758894260568,
            "percentiles": [
                0.0,
                0.0,
                0.0,
                0.0,
                0.0,
                0.22,
                2.62,
                3.66,
                3.87,
                3.98,
                4.09,
                4.2,
                4.33,
                4.49,
                4.79,
                6.69400000000001,
                9.74299999999998,
                18.872,
                32.234
            ],
            "prio": 2
        },
        {
            "id": 1995249,
            "index": 1,
            "name": "iso_0057",
            "unit": "t/h",
            "device": "49700062",
            "code": "iso_0057",
            "count": 8067,
            "std": 81.4727887924538,
            "min": 0.0,
            "max": 277.1,
            "mean": 66.4214788645097,
            "percentiles": [
                0.0,
                0.0,
                0.0,
                0.0,
                0.0,
                0.0,
                0.0,
                0.0,
                0.0,
                0.0,
                0.0,
                64.5519999999999,
                128.509,
                153.67,
                164.72,
                171.156,
                176.18,
                181.524,
                188.78
            ],
            "prio": 2
        }
      ],
      "user": "test@test.nl",
      "centroid": "POINT (54.423692227112667 7.45637103322727)",
      "mappings": null
}
```

I want to get all the document documents where `data_type = ISOBUS` and `created starts with 2021`. However, when I try to query the **created** field it always returns 0 hits no matter how I write my query. I also have to add keyword to my query else the server just returns an internal server error. Why is keyword added to some field names in a query?

**1.**

```
{
    "query": {
        "prefix": { "created.keyword":"2021" }
    }
}
```

**2.**

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [{
                "prefix": { "created.keyword":"2021" }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

**3.**

```
{
    "query": {
        "wildcard": { 
            "created.keyword": {"value": "2021*"}
        }
    }
}
```

**4.**

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                { "term": { "data_type.keyword": "ISOBUS"} },
                { "prefix": { "created.keyword":"2021" } }]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on your mappings. The best bet is to use the `date` type for your `created` field:

```json
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "data_type": {
                "type": "keyword"
            },
            "created": {
                "type": "date"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can index your doc:

```json
POST index/_doc

{
    "created": "2021-10-11T17:25:16.754278",
    "data_type": "ISOBUS"
}
```

And then you can query:

```json
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {"term": {"data_type": "ISOBUS"}},
                {"range": {
                    "created": {
                        "gte": "2021",
                        "lt": "2022"
                    }
                }}
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

The idea is you want to search for the exact year 2021, so you can get the range to be >= 2021 and < 2022, so it is 2021 in general. I removed other fields from my example to make the code simpler.